# Update a record or insert it if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have a field 'JobNo' which is a unique number.  However, some of the records have been accidentally deleted so if the job has been deleted I would like to insert a new record.

The code to update is:

```
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset, x As Long
    With rst
        .Open "SELECT * FROM ActJobs WHERE JobNo=" & frmd.Cells(2, 19), _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=K:\KKDB.accdb", adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        For x = 0 To 38
            If x = 17 Or x = 20 Or x = 23 Then
                If frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) <> "" Then
                    .fields(x) = DateValue(frmd.Cells(2, x + 3))
                End If
            Else
                If x = 24 And frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = "" Then frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = 0
                If x = 25 And frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = "" Then frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = 0
                If x = 26 And frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = "" Then frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = 0
                .fields(x) = frmd.Cells(2, x + 3)
            End If
        Next
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
```

I read about INSERT INTO and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (which is what I think I need) but I can't work out how to do it with the above code.
Any help would be most appreciated.

Best regards and thanks, Paul Ked

PS I've also posted this here https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?172,678526,678526#msg-678526 but I don't think it is in the correct forum!

Comment: Hi. As I understand, you are checking if records have been deleted if the content of  
(frmd.Cells(2, x + 3) = ""), so you'like to insert again it's info. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi.  Not quite, the contents of frmd.cells(2,19) will always have a job number in it.  If this job number isn't found in the 'JobNo' field in the database then INSERT the record.  If it is found then UPDATE the record.  Thanks

Comment: Hi. If you want to insert, I'm missing the "addnew" instruction.
As I understand, your loop will only update records that come from the select instruction.
You maybe have to create a new record every time you have not found.

https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=219149

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/addnew-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes! The code I have posted only Updates existing records, which is fine if the record exists in the database.  If the record with JobNo 'frmd.cells(2,19)' does not exist, then I want to create a new record.